# Test if the input stream not empty without consuming data from it

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cat

Consider next snippet.

```
generate_build_specs(){
  echo ubuntu gcc9 debug
  echo macos clang debug
  echo macos gcc10 release
  echo macos clang release
}
generate_build_specs | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/macos/ && /release/' |
  if input_data_available ;then
      echo "FIXME. Cannot build 'macos release' until it is fixed. Buildspec dropped: $(cat)"
  fi
```

My idea is to echo message with contents of input stream only if data in stream available. Something like `peek(char)` in stream, not taking it from there.

Of course, I know a workaround. i.e

```
var="$(cat)"; if test -n "$var"; echo "blah:: $var" ; fi
```

Comment: This is not a bash question, but a conceptual question.  You cannot do this.  Suppose you had such a test and determined that the input stream is empty.  .0007ns later, there could be data on the stream, so your test is pointless.

Comment: I can test for EOF. In C/C++ i can for sure. So there could be a tool that does the job, isn't it?

Comment: Is the `$(cat)` in your code trying to work on the unfiltered (by awk) output of `generate_build_specs`?

Comment: How do you test for EOF in C?  You can do a `getchar`, and if it gives you EOF then you know that the other side of the pipe is closed.  Or you could mark the file descriptor non-blocking and know that there is not currently data available to read, but that doesn't tell you whether or not the next read will return data.   If you don't mark the fd non-blocking, then the attempt to read may block and tell you nothing.  The only way to test is to attempt to read data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, `$(cat)` wanna take full output of `awk`, `input_data_available` checks if there anything to `cat`, but does not consume data from stream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, in C we can `feof()`, or `getchar`, then `ungetc()`. In C++ there is `ifstream::eof()` and `ifstream::good()`

Comment: That's not how `feof()` works.  At all.  `feof` only tells you if a read operation return EOF because of an error or because you reached end of file.  You can `getchar`, then `ungetc`, but that's not determining if there is data in the file without reading it; it is explicitly reading a byte (that byte is now not available to any other reader).

Comment: `ungetc()` only works with language libraries that provide buffered I/O. You can't `ungetc()` or do anything like it with unbuffered IO, because the buffer is local to each process's memory; you can't hand a character back to the kernel and say "put that back in the FD so the next program I run inheriting the descriptor can read it". And because shell languages are _all about_ handing control off between programs, bash's reading from stdin is unbuffered.

Comment: So, there is no way to check if a stream is ended without reading at least one char from it?

Comment: @kyb, you can `poll` the fd and check if POLLNVAL is set in `revents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the discussion, I realized that

> there is no way to check if a stream is ended without reading at least one char from it.

`input_data_available` could not be implemented in Bash. It is a conceptual question on streams.

So the current solution is to store input to variable, then work on it.

```
var="$(cat)"; if test -n "$var"; then echo "::ERROR:: $var" ; fi
```

A better (i.e. laconic) way to do the same is:

```
sed -zE 's,^.+$,::ERROR:: \0\n,'
```

It means *prepend string and output only if input is not empty*. Regexp `^.+$` checks if there is at least one symbol. But I think as all oneliners this one is harder to read.

Thank you everybody for participation.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but for your case equivalent in functionality:

```
if generate_build_specs | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/macos/ && /release/' | grep -q .
then
  echo No data produced
fi
```

If we are picky, we should point out that if the pipe produces data consisting of empty lines only, this would also cause a *no data produced*

If you really have exactly that awk command which you have posted (and did not show a simplified version here to explain your point), you could perhaps also have written

```
if generate_build_specs | grep -i macos | grep -iqv 'release'
then
  ..echo "No data produced which contains the strings 'macos' and 'release'"
fi
```

This means that the string `macos` must appear earlier in a line than the string `release`. Since I don't know how the expected output of `generate_builds_specs` looks like, I can't say whether this approach will work in your case.

Comment: string macos may appear before or after release. order does not matter

Comment: As U can see i wanna write message only if there is data in stream, and do not echo if there is nothing.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now, macos and release must occur in any order in some line; otherwise an error message is displayed. As a side note: Maybe it would make sense to write the error message to stderr instead of stdout...

Comment: Thank you for effort. But i need to display dropped buildspecs in error message. As i told in question.

Comment: In this case, you have to store your input into a variable and decide on the content of the variable.

Comment: Yes. This us how I do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to peel to the stream. Just store the output in a variable.

```
buildspec=$(generate_build_specs | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/macos/ && /release/')
if [[ -n "${buildspec}" ]]; then
   printf "%s\n" "FIXME. Cannot build 'macos release' until it is fixed." \
        "Buildspec dropped:" "${buildspec}"
fi
```

I used `printf` for getting newlines whre you might want them, you can also use `echo` 3 times.

Comment: Yes. I am using this solution.